# For each attribute of template c++

Tags: c++, templates, ros, telemetry

I'm trying to make templates in c++ with incrementing arguments of the template.

```
 void subcribePosition(ros::Publisher& posGPS_pub, mavsdk::Telemetry & telemetry){
        telemetry.subscribe_position([&](mavsdk::Telemetry::Position pos){
            mavsdk_interface::gpsPos msg;
            msg.latitude_deg = pos.latitude_deg;
            msg.longitude_deg = pos.longitude_deg;
            msg.absolute_altidue_m = pos.absolute_altitude_m;
            msg.relative_altitude_m = pos.relative_altitude_m;
            posGPS_pub.publish(msg);
    });
```

In this code I'm trying to assign each argument in `pos` to each argument in `msg`. Is it possible to do this using templates ?

Meaning I want to have a template class to which I pass the struct `mavsdk::Telemetry::Position` and each argument is assigned to ros struct `msg`

Comment: The two classes look very similar. Do they inherit from one another? Need to see more code to be able to say for sure.

Comment: No, they aren't inherit from one another. Only names are the same, so if the names are the same can we somehow do it with templates?

Comment: No, it can't be done with templates. But if you really want it and the members are in the same order, then there might be a way with e.g. magic_get (not recommended).